# How to test difference between weighted and non-weighted slope in R?

Tags: r, regression, weighted-regression

I have a dataframe with the following column: Year, Temperature, Num.Species which are all numeric variables. Each row represent the number of species observed a certain year and the mean temperature that year.

I want to test if the regression slope of Year~Temperature, differs from the regression slope of Year~Temperature when using Num.Species as a weighting factor.

From what I understood so far, it is possible to do this with an ANCOVA. But there is no categorical variable in my data.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by a weighting factor? Do you mean you want to add it as a predictor in the model, or do you mean that you want to use it as a survey/frequency weight?

Comment: Also, ANCOVA=regression. Maybe you should use regression.

Comment: ANCOVA is a special case of regression for comparing categorical variables. Just use regression.

Comment: Why are you using Year as the response? Are you trying to predict Year based on Temperature?